# GregorianCalendar gives wrong day number

Tags: java, date, kotlin, java.util.calendar

I've the below code, where I'm trying to post a sales order transaction, with date and qty, once I', `getting` the day of the transaction date, it is lagging 31 days, and apparently the Dec 1st is considered to be day number 1 in he year!! Anything wrong in my code, or how can I fix it?!

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.*

data class transaction (var date: LocalDate, var quantity: Double) {

    private var calendar: Calendar = 
            GregorianCalendar(date.year, date.monthValue, date.dayOfMonth)
    var day: Int
        get() = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)
        set(value) = TODO()
}

val formatter: DateTimeFormatter
    get() = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var salesOrders = ArrayList<transaction>()
    salesOrders.add(transaction(LocalDate.parse("01.01.2018", formatter), 5.0))

    println(salesOrders[0].date.dayOfMonth) // prints: 1
    println(salesOrders[0].date.monthValue) // prints: 1
    println(salesOrders[0].date.year)       // prints: 2018
    println(salesOrders[0].day)             // prints 32 ??!!
}
```

Comment: When you can use the modern Java date and time classes like `LocalDate`, I recommend you avoid the outdated classes like `GregorianCalendar`.Just let your private variable be a `LocalDate` and use its `getDayOfYear` method.

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. I used it because in real I need to use the `calendar.timeInMillis` as I need a unique identifier for each day over the years, I could not fine similar thing in `LocalDate`

Comment: `LocalDate.toEpochDay` is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you drop the use of `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` completely.

```
    println(salesOrders[0].date.dayOfYear)  // prints 1
```

I haven’t got Kotlin, so I have not tested. Should there be a typo you cannot solve, please follow up in a comment.

`Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` are long outdated, and the modern Java date and time API to which `LocalDate` belongs is so much nicer to work with. And offers all the functionality you could wish for.

I understood form your comment that you need a unique identifier for each day over the years. You have been using `calendar.timeInMillis`. First, that is a poor identifier because it varies with time zone. Instead I suggest using the `LocalDate` itself or its string representation that you get from `date.toString`. If you need a numeric identifier (like you had from `calendar.timeInMillis`), you may use `date.toEpochDay`. This is a count of days since the epoch of January 1, 1970, so is unique for each day (and unaffected by time zone).

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDate.monthValue` is in range `1..12` while `Calendar.JANUARY` is `0` therefore `Calendar` month is in range `0..11`

So the below code should work:

```
private var calendar: Calendar = 
            GregorianCalendar(date.year, date.monthValue - 1, date.dayOfMonth)
```

Comment: Don't you mean `date.monthValue-1`

Comment: @s1m0nw1 the month `Jan` is required to be `1` instead of `0` to be red correctly

Comment: @HasanAYousef `date.monthValue` has range `1..12`, so `date.monthValue + 1` has range `2..13`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher having it `date.monthValue+1` worked perfectly with me!!!

Comment: I hand translated the code in the question into Java (haven’t got Kotlin) and made the change suggested in this answer. Now the fourth iine of output is `60` instead of `32`. I believe that `1` was expected and desired.

Comment: @HasanAYousef I tried the `+ 1` variant in https://try.kotlinlang.org and it returned `60` as last value